# Scraping dynamic DataTable of many pages but same URL

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, datatables, screen-scraping

I have experience with C and I'm starting to approach Python, mostly for fun.
I am trying to scrape this page here [https://www.justetf.com/it/find-etf.html?groupField=index&from=search&/it/find-etf.html%3F1-1.0-esearch-etfsPanel](http://justetf.com).
Since the table, with the content I'm interested on, is dynamically created after connecting to the page, I'm using:

- Selenium to load the page in the browser
- Beautiful soup 4 for scraping the data loaded

At the moment I'm able to scrape all the fields of interest of the first 25 entries, the ones which are loaded once connected to the page. I can have up to 100 entries in one page but there are 1045 entries in total, which are split in different pages. The problem is that the url is the same for all the pages and the content of the table is dynamically loaded at runtime.
What I would like to do is find a way to be able to scrape all the entries, which are 1045. Reading through the internet I have understood I should send a proper POST request (I've also founded that they are retrieving data from https://www.finanztreff.de/) from my code, get the data from the response and scrape it.
I can see two possibilities :

1. Retrieve all the entries in once
2. Retrieve one page after the other and scrape one after the other

I have no idea how to build up the POST request.
I think there is no need to post the code but if needed I can re-edit the question.
Thanks in advance to everybody.

**EDITED**

Here you go with some code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('some path\\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
                                 
url = "https://www.justetf.com/it/find-etf.html"
browser.get(url)
delay = 5 # seconds
try:
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'Alerian')))
print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
print ("Loading took too much time!")

page_source = browser.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
```

from here on I just play a bit with bs4 APIs.

Comment: When loading the page it redirects to `https://www.justetf.com/de-en/`. Do we need to be signed in? If not - what table are you trying to scrape? Also please edit the code you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks @MendelG, edited in the description. You don't need to be signed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (getting all the data at once):

```
import requests as r

link = 'https://www.justetf.com/it/find-etf.html?groupField=index&from=search&/it/find-etf.html%3F1-1.0-esearch-etfsPanel'
link2 = 'https://www.justetf.com/servlet/etfs-table'

data = {
    'draw': 1,
    'start': 0,
    'length': 10000000,
    'lang': 'it',
    'country': 'DE',
    'universeType': 'private',
    'etfsParams': link.split('?')[1]
}


res = r.post(link2, data=data)
result = res.json()
print(len(result["data"]))
```

EDIT: For the explanation, I did open network tab in chrome and click on the next pages to see what requests have been made, and I noticed that a `POST` requests was made to `link2` with a lot of parameters and most were mandatory.
For the needed parameters, `draw` I only needed one draw (one request), `start` starting from position 0, `length` I used a big number to scrape everything at once. If length was for example 10, you'd need a lot of draws, they go like `draw=2&start=10&length=10`, `draw=3&start=20&length=10` and so on. For `lang`, `country` and `universeType` I didn't know the exact use but removing them would reject the request. And last the `etfsParams` is what comes after '?' in `link`.

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly and, with this solution, I don't even need to use selenium or even bsp4. In your answer there is a bit of lack of explanation. Do you mind explaning me how you proceeded to get this result? Why thos parameters? How did you get which were the parameters and the links? I would be also interested in the process of understanding the problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I did add a quick explanation, if something is unclear, feel free to mention the part so I could elaborate more on it.

Comment: Thanks again! One thing I would like to know more, if possible, how did you understand which were the mandatory fields? How do you debug the code for the POST request?

Comment: Usually they are all mandatory, but this once had tons of fields that goes like columns[1][2] with different numbers and all, so I just thought why not remove them and it ended up working.There was probably no checking on the background on those fields.